# Prevent my website from initially loading bad CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

My website is done and I have noticed that on slow internets, the website would initially load bad CSS where buttons would collide and mash up.

Basically looks terrible. And I have been looking for methods of how to resolve this issue and all I have been reading is "Get better hosting service" and to "Minify my CSS and JS".

But would this really help. Could this be because I disabled my CSS/JS caching?
.htaccess code below:

```
    # disable CSS/JS caching

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Here are the images of how it looks before on initial load and after:

[image: image one of initial load]

**and**

[image: image two of after load]

Comment: You can get rid of your custom fonts. I don't think the CSS file is slowing you down. The assets ( fonts, images, etc. ) are what is.

Comment: Why not just add a loader with a solid background to mask the initial DOM render?

Like this example: http://cleanenergyco.com/projects/

Comment: It is not loading a bad CSS. It has no CSS while your CSS is loading so it just shows the html without styling. Once the CSS is loading it is applied to your page. Your CSS is way too heavy and that is why it is taking longer to load. Either trim down the CSS or show a loader while CSS is being downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable your CSS caching in .htaccess, it would basically just show your website as unstyled rather than horribly styled for the initial loading period.

You could also just try this simple approach:

```
<head><div id="loadOverlay" style="background-color:#333; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2000;"></div>
```

and at the bottom of your CSS place this line: 
   `#loadOverlay{display: none;}`

This will essentially let your website load under a canvas, and once loaded the canvas will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the overlay!

Comment: Thanks, I will try implementing this method, seems the most reasonable. I will also try to improve the hosting plan and minify CSS&JS. That will make the site extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

When the internet is slow, and as css files are loaded asynchronously and browser will display the html elements without styles in the css file, you can put the important styles for layout in the same html page, so it is may a workaround for this.

Comment: Going around is not a way, there should be a technical solution.. Placing the CSS code in the HTML code will slow down the site even more.

Comment: I don't the exact case of your code, but in there are two options : put the css code (which needs much time to load) in some file so the page will loaded fast but will not have styles initially, or putting the css in the same html file, the page will need much time to load, but it will have styles loaded on the same time. Again I don't know what is the exact case for your code, you may need to optimize some fonts or images sizes which need much time for loading.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really good reason to avoid caching, I would recommend to not disable caching. Your problem is the amount of fonts and images, so in a slow connection, the CSS will take longer to load, preventing a good look. Use CSS inside the HTML, like this:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    #sidebarMenu {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }    
</style>
```

Instead of using a separate CSS file. This will speed up loading, and make sure the CSS is there when the HTML is loaded.

Comment: I will enable CSS/JS caching after I am done with the site, because it is so annoying at the moment to keep clearing the cache manually thats why I disabled it.